# How to fix the horse glitch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I fix the glitch where the third person camera when riding a horse is stuck on it's feet? I have tried downloading mods to make it better but it failed.

Answer (score 2):

I've played my time on Skyrim [Legendary Edition] for PS3 and I actually had this glitch occur to me. All that you need to do in order to fix the perspective is go do another task which requires the game to change perspective and the horse perspective should be fixed. Tasks that change perspective are thing like using the forge, sharpening a weapon at the grinder, hammering armor, using the tanning rack, chopping wood. If that didn't work then try using a carriage. Finally, if none of that worked then go ahead and fast travel into a town and try riding your horse again. If none of this worked I would try and go back to a previous save where the perspective worked. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but it usually goes away within a few seconds. Try making your horse stand up while youre on it or getting off and back on.